# Does the transformation $(A\otimes A)B(A\otimes A)^{-1}$ have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, tensor-products, similar-matrices

If $B$ is a $n^2\times n^2$ complex valued matrix and $A$ is a nonsingular $n\times n$ complex valued matrix then define the transformation:
$$B_{new}=(A\otimes A)B(A\otimes A)^{-1}$$

I'm wondering if this kind of transformation has a name and if there are any known properties.

Comment: Yes it's the Kronecker product. I just edited the question to correct the dimensions.

Comment: It is a special case of a similar matrix (or conjugate matrix, if you think of similar matrices as being conjugate in the general linear group).

Comment: If $B$ can itself be written as the Kronecker product $B=B_1\otimes B_2$, then this is just a similarity transformation of both $B_1,B_2$ with respect to $A$.